# See Balances on mainnet-fork?

Tags: solidity, python, brownie, balances, mainnet

I'm currently watching my first smart contracts tutorial by freecodecamp and it works fine but, I have one question:
How can I check the balance of my mainnet-fork account(s)? When I work with Rinkeby or Görli I can simply check the success of my transactions via MetaMask but how can I check my mainnet-fork balance? Where & how?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're using Metamask, the balances are shown in the usual place...

Comment: @0xSanson NO! When I run the code on mainnet-fork? It works, but I don't know where to look at the accounts, and balance, is there a specific comand I have to use?

Answer (score 0):

print(f'account bal.: {account.balance()})

works for any network I've tried, which is to say mainnet-fork, avax-test, and ganache. If you are using the 'get_account()' function in [patrick collins video](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1ONGR_enUS1030US1030&sxsrf=APwXEdfdryG_VSU8NLhB_8ALCvlzMLkx5Q:1683081434190&q=smart+contract+patrick+collins&tbm=vid&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZ8Yz4jtj-AhW4IzQIHRFtAskQ0pQJegQIChAB&biw=1024&bih=625&dpr=1#fpstate=ive&vld=cid:2f41d684,vid:M576WGiDBdQ) then pay attention to the fact that the line

```
  if network.show_active() in LOCAL_BLOCKCHAIN_ENVIRONMENTS:
       return accounts[0]
```

returns a brownie (ganache-cli?) generated account rather than your wallets account if 'mainnet-fork' is in 'LOCAL_BLOCKCHAIN_ENVIRONMENTS'. So you'd be seeing that account balance rather than your wallets.